# GUI tool for managing Samba shares?

Tags: samba, gui

My understanding is that swat is no longer actively maintained. [1]
Is there a GUI tool for maintaining Samba shares.

PS Platform:LDME

[1] Not only that I can't get it to work with xinetd on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Webmin (http://www.webmin.com/) is a fantastic tool used for server management in general. It uses a web interface.

The samba component can add/remove/configure shares as well as change config settings all through a GUI.